# Using Eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker, need to preset year to 65 years ago

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have an application for medical professionals servicing Medicare patients typically in their 60's to 100's and we I use Eonasdan [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) to allow them to select birthdates like so:

JavaScript:

```
$('.birthDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'M/D/YYYY',
    maxDate: (new Date()),// used to disallow future dates
    showClose: true,
    viewMode: 'years'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group birthDateTimePicker">
    <input id="birthDt" name="birthDt" type="text" placeholder="Birth Date"
            class="form-control col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" required />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

This produces a display that initially does not have a date selected, but says:`Birth date` in the input box.  The problem is, it defaults to 2015, so selecting the year is painfully slow due to the advanced age of most of the patients. I tried setting the defaultDate like so:

```
$('.birthDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment().subtract(68, 'y'),
    format: 'M/D/YYYY',
    maxDate: (new Date()),// used to disallow future dates
    showClose: true,
    viewMode: 'years'
});
```

But now, instead of it displaying `Birth date` in the input box, it displays an actual date like `12/10/1947` in the input box. I want to pre-set the starting year, BUT NOT pre-select the entire date. The birthday is VERY important in the medical treatment they receive AND is used with their name for identification, and the LAST thing I want is for someone to forget to enter the birthdate, and because it has already pre-selected a specific date, they get the wrong birthday. So, how do I make it easy for the medical professional to select the year, but not have it arbitrarily enter the wrong date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the latest version you can set your options as such:

```
viewDate: moment().subtract(68, 'y'),
format: 'M/D/YYYY',
maxDate: moment(),
showClose: true,
viewMode: 'years'
```

`viewDate` is an option that will cause the picker to open at the specified date.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I saw that in the docs and guessed viewDate might do that (documentation was rather sparse, so it was not obvious what viewDate would do - a couple more sentences would make it much clearer...), so I grabbed the latest versions of moment.js and  bootstrap-datetimepicker, and I tried it before I posted. Unfortunately it does not work.  It does not pre-populate the input box (as desired), but when I click on the calendar icon, the year selection box pops up just like before with '< 2010 - 2021 >' at the top and '2015' selected :-(

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/o87jvk52/ please provide a jsfilddle other wise

Comment: yes, I saw your jsfiddle worked :-) Not sure what the differences are between mine and your fiddle.  I am using the latest jQuery, I am only using moment.js, not the moment-with-locales.js that your fiddle uses.  Also, when I try to use the _bootstrap-datetimepicker.less supplied with your latest version of DTP, it is giving errors that @ screen-sm-min @ screen-md-min are not defined (going from memory).  What are the dependencies for the version you posted on fiddle?

Comment: I have to use `useCurrent: false` to the viewDate works