# Bootstrap Datetimepicker Pop Up Shows Disabled Dates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, calendar, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker, disable

Following is my code

```
$('#dob').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  maxDate: new Date("2009", "01", "01"),
  useCurrent: false
});
```

But when I test my interface it pops up already disabled dates (current month). This is not user friendly. How can I fix it so it opens my maximum allowed month? (January, 2009) Please check following image for reference.

I googled but found no answeres for this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker, need to preset year to 65 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207520/using-eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker-need-to-preset-year-to-65-years-ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`viewDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewdate) option:

> This will change the `viewDate` without changing or setting the selected date.

Here a live sample:

```js
$('#dob').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  maxDate: new Date(2009, 0, 1),
  useCurrent: false,
  viewDate: new Date(2009, 0, 1)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want for dates after January 2009 not to show up.

```
     $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                 format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',  
                 maxDate:new Date("2008", "12", "1"),
                 });
```

I tried this on fiddle and it seems to work, started from new Date("2008", "12", "1") because when given new Date("2009", "01", "01") it starts from Feburary 2009 instead of January

https://jsfiddle.net/HarveyQ/0xq8n62u/26/

I researched the [document for datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#extraformats), but couldn't find an option to hide disabled dates.

Comment: I get this error: Why? `TypeError: option startDate is not recognized! bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:8:22416`

Comment: Sorry, it seems I looked up to another datepicker and startDate is a method for that one. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I set Jan 2009 as the min month, if you want it to be your max month, just replace minDate with maxDate

Comment: Well, I don't want a default date and I don't want to give the user the ability to select any date higher than 2008/01/01. So that's why I want them disabled. That's done with maxDate but, it shows disabled dates at initial popup. That's the problem.